# Combining selects depending on which table the result comes from

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a db table called Document that contains rows for all the documents I own. I have another db table called Shared that has records for documents (owned by other people) that the specified user_id has access to. So if i were user1 for ex, I would have my documents in the Documents table and documents by user2 that I have access to stored in the Shared table with my user_id and user2's document_ids.

```
Document
id
user_id
type
name
permissions

Shared
id
document_id
used_id
permissions
```

Each entry in the Documents table has permissions = "all". Each entry in the shared table has vaying levels of permissions such as {write, read, delete}. In my query to get back all documents owned/accessible for user foo, I would like to get back the proper permissions depending on whether the record was from Documents or Shared. I have a basic query now that pulls back all documents that i 
own and have access to. My attempt is something like this:

```
Select d.id, d.user_id, d.permissions 
from Document d
   left join Shared s on s.document_id = d.id 
where s.user_id = 1
```

Another attempt:

```
Select d.id, d.user_id, 
       COALESCE(s.permissions, d.permissions) as permissions 
from Documents d 
   left join Shared s on s.document_id = d.id and s.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: Is id in the Shared table a surrogate key?

Comment: id in the shared table has nothing to do with the document or user tables. It is just a simple autoincrementing primary key

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I believe you just need to union the results from each table:

```
select * from 
    (select d.id as document_id, d.user_id, 'all' as permissions, d.name
    from t_documents d
    union all
    select s.document_id, s.user_id, s.permissions, dtl.name
    from t_shared s
    left join t_documents dtl
    on s.document_id = dtl.id) tot
where tot.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: would that be more performant than the following?:
Select d.id, d.user_id, COALESCE(s.permissions, d.permissions) as permissions from Documents d left join Shared s on s.document_id = d.id and s.user_id = 1;

Comment: Given your description, your tables are mutually exclusive, where the documents table has the permissions of the owner of the document and the Shared table has permissions for anyone other than the owner per document. You wouldn't use a join here because you'd ideally never have a record for the same user/document combination in both tables. The union is a result of this mutual exclusion.

Comment: I see. Performance wise, would the union yield a more efficient query over the join? Also, I believe your answer doesnt quite work because right now it's not querying by a user_id

Comment: Also, lets say the Document table has many more fields and the Shared table has only the necessary fields to identify the user-> document mapping. I dont think the union will work there as you need all the columns from the Document table for each entry you find in the Shared table right?

Comment: It's not a difference in performance, but a difference in function. I'll update the query to show how you can query on user id. You can limit the fields by specifying explicitly which fields you want (like it is above). You can see that I'm only selecting document_id, user_id, and permissions for both tables.

Comment: I just updated the description to make it closer to the real world use case I have

Comment: I dont think the above will work though. I would like full details about a document that I fetched from the Shared table. But the shared table does not have enough document info to tell me the name or type for example. i would have to take the document ids i get from the shared table and requery for them in the documents table to get the other fields right?

Comment: so you want to append information about the documents as well?

Comment: yep, thats what i was attempting in my join statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124695/discussion-between-john-baum-and-mackers).